# FineUploader signing in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

Do you have any examples of s3 server signing in ruby with FineUploader.com? I have tried many variations on this:

```
if(@valid_data.headers.present?)
  signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(
          OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'),
          S3_SECRET,
          @valid_data.headers).gsub(/\n/, '')
else

 signature = Base64.encode64(
    OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(
      OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'),
      S3_SECRET,
      Base64.encode64(@valid_data.headers)
   )
  ).gsub(/\n/, '')

  details.policy = Base64.encode64({  expiration: @valid_data.expiration,
                                  conditions: @valid_data.conditions
                                }.to_json
                              ).gsub(/\n|\r/, '')
end

details.signature = signature

render :json => details, :status => 200 and return
```

But cannot get the sign I make match the sign amazon gives, hence I get an error on each upload I do

I checked the github repo, the rails s3 help only points to https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/rails.md which points to https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/wiki/Rails---CarrierWave which does not seemily have any connection to FineUploader.
Best,
Vinny

## EDIT(to clarify)

For 5mb files, signing the headers params works fine with the code from http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434/#signyours3postform

```
 signature = Base64.encode64(
    OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(
        OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'),
        S3_SECRET, @valid_data.headers)
    ).gsub("\n","")
```

For sub 5MB files, it needs a policy and a signature
FineUploader gives me a "conditions" parameter, which I use to get all the needed info:

```
conds =  [
      {"acl" => "private"},
      {"bucket" => conditions[1][:bucket]},
      {"Content-Type" => conditions[2]["Content-Type"]},
      {"success_action_status" => "200"},
      {"key" => conditions[4][:key]},
      {"x-amz-meta-qqfilename" => conditions[5]["x-amz-meta-qqfilename"]},
      {"content-length-range" => [content_length_range[1], content_length_range[2]]}
    ]

   policy = Base64.encode64({  "expiration" => @valid_data.expiration.to_s,
                                      "conditions" => conds
                                    }.to_json).
                          gsub("\n","")

    signature = Base64.encode64(
    OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(
        OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'),
        S3_SECRET, policy)
    ).gsub("\n","")
```

AWS always responds with " Invalid Policy: Invalid Simple-Condition: value mu.." after its 100% gone up to aws. I also cant seem to find a policy signing function within https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby

Also, according to ruby aws-sdk(https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/lib%2Faws%2Fcore%2Fsigners%2Fbase.rb), ruby uses sha256 instead of sha1

Comment: When I stopped passing content-length-range into conds, signatures worked as expected. closing

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear to me but if you are trying to upload a file to **S3** directly, you can sign the request in this way (taken from [s3_direct_upload](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload) gem). I use this gem in my application to upload files directly to **S3**.

```
    def policy
      Base64.encode64(policy_data.to_json).gsub("\n", "")
    end

    def policy_data
      {
        expiration: @options[:expiration],
        conditions: [
          ["starts-with", "$utf8", ""],
          ["starts-with", "$key", @options[:key_starts_with]],
          ["starts-with", "$x-requested-with", ""],
          ["content-length-range", 0, @options[:max_file_size]],
          ["starts-with","$content-type", @options[:content_type_starts_with] ||""],
          {bucket: @options[:bucket]},
          {acl: @options[:acl]},
          {success_action_status: "201"}
        ] + (@options[:conditions] || [])
      }
    end

    def signature
      Base64.encode64(
        OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(
          OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1'),
          @options[:aws_secret_access_key], policy
        )
      ).gsub("\n", "")
    end
```

You can see full code here: https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload/blob/master/lib/s3_direct_upload/form_helper.rb

Comment: My question concerns an s3 uploading tool, fineuploader: http://docs.fineuploader.com/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html  Signing examples exist for most other languages, but I do not understand the rails example, as per https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server

Comment: As linked to in the Fine Uploader S3 documentation, here are examples in several languages, including Ruby: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434/#signyours3postform

Comment: @user1741832, I think your problem is that you are creating `signature` before creating `policy`. Create `policy` first, because that is used in creating `signature`. See the code above and you will see what I am saying.

Comment: The policy already exists.  It is created by Fine Uploader S3, sent to the server, and expects a signature in return.

Comment: Hi Ray, Clarified my question above, sorry that it was confusing

Answer (score 1):

When I stopped passing content-length-range into conds, signatures worked as expected